# Limit of an indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I would appreciate some help figuring out a way to solve the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(x-e^x \right)$$

I know that $e^x$ is much larger than $x$, and therefore the limit will be $-\infty$.  What I would like to know is whether or not there is a way to solve this algebraically.  Any one able to help?  I can't seem to force L'Hopital's Rule here, nor was I able to use the limit definition of $e$.

Thanks,
Mada

Comment: It possibly becomes more explicit if you write $x - e^x = -e^x (1-\frac{x}{e^x})$?

Comment: Write the limit expression as $x(1-{e^x\over x})$. Show that $e^x/x$ tends to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity. then deduce your limit is...

Comment: I really hope your teacher isn't asking you this with the hopes that you rearrange it and then use L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 3):

You can do some rearranging:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x-e^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}xe^{-x}/e^{-x}+1/e^{-x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x/e^{x}-1}{e^{-x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}-e^{x}=-\infty$$
L'hopitals is used implicity here with $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{e^x}$.

Comment: Just one tip, instead of writing the long `\rightarrow` which produces $\rightarrow$, write only `\to` instead which produces the same result: $\to$. +1 through. ;-)